# Capacity Forecasting ( CPU/Memory/Disk)

Tags: database, postgresql, capacity, capacity-planning

Trying to forecast the above metrics for our postgres database servers.
We have nagios and cacti. How have you done this?

Answer (score 1):

**Disk:**

You can experiment with [`pg_column_size`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) to figure out how big a value (or a table row) will be on disk.

There will be a lot of overhead: headers, empty space in disk blocks, and of 
course all the space for indexes you create. Estimate something between three and ten times the space got with `pg_column_size`.

You will also have to reserve disk space for archived transaction logs (WAL).

**Memory:**

As much as possible for a busy database.

**CPU:**

As many cores as you expect concurrent queries.

Comment: We have the above metrics for a year and a decent anticipation of the growth.This will help.